# error while importing seaborn (invalid matplotlib parameter)

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I run into an error when trying to import seaborn. I have matplotlib v3.0.3 installed and seaborn v0.9.0. The code I try to run is:

```
#! /usr/bin/python3

import seaborn
```

Running the code above yields this output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/transaid/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/matplotlib/__init__.py", line 861, in __setitem__
    cval = self.validate[key](val)
KeyError: 'axes.color_cycle'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./testmatplotlib.py", line 3, in <module>
    import seaborn
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/seaborn/__init__.py", line 13, in <module>
    set()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/seaborn/rcmod.py", line 98, in set
    set_palette(palette, color_codes=color_codes)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/seaborn/rcmod.py", line 491, in set_palette
    mpl.rcParams["axes.color_cycle"] = list(colors)
  File "/home/transaid/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/matplotlib/__init__.py", line 868, in __setitem__
    'list of valid parameters.' % (key,))
KeyError: 'axes.color_cycle is not a valid rc parameter. See rcParams.keys() for a list of valid parameters.'
```

Any clues as to what goes wrong and how to solve this?

Comment: This possibly looks like a bug in Seaborn. It might be an idea to report it at https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/issues/.

Comment: You have a mismatch between seaborn and matplotlib versions. It pretty much looks like your seaborn version is much too old (or your matplotlib version much too new). I would recommend updating seaborn.

Comment: Seaborn v0.9.0 is the most recent version. I did notice however that I have two versions op matplotlib on my system. One in python2 (v2.2.4) and one in python 3 (v3.0.3). I assume seaborn is looking at the v3.0.3 and this is indeed too new. Can I somehow force seaborn to use matplotlib v2.2.4? I am not sure if other applications require the more recent matplotlib, so I'd prefer not to uninstall that one

Comment: seaborn 0.9 and matplotlib 2.2 are new enough for this error not to occur. So something else is strange about your systems. Notice how the first error is raised from `/home/transaid/.local/lib/python3.5` while the second from `/usr/lib/python3`.